# What are AWT's HierarchyListener and HierarchyEvent Equivalents in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, awt

In Java AWT, we have the ability to add a [`HierarchyListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/HierarchyListener.html) to receive hierarchy changed events from a component when the hierarchy to which that container belongs changes. By receiving a [`HierarchyEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/HierarchyEvent.html) (An event which indicates a change to the `Component` hierarchy to which `Component` belongs), we can listen to the following change events:

- Hierarchy Change Events (HierarchyListener)

  - Addition of an ancestor
  - Removal of an ancestor
  - Hierarchy made displayable
  - Hierarchy made undisplayable
  - Hierarchy shown on the screen (both visible and displayable)
  - Hierarchy hidden on the screen (either invisible or undisplayable)
- Ancestor Reshape Events (HierarchyBoundsListener)

  - An ancestor was resized
  - An ancestor was moved

Sample code:

```java
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.addHierarchyListener((event) -> {
    if((event.getChangeFlags() & HierarchyEvent.HIERARCHY_CHANGED) != 0) {
        // hierarchy tree changed
    }
});
```

How can I listen to the same type of events in JavaFX? As an example, how can I get notified when any of a `Node`'s ancestors get shown or hidden in JavaFX?